# Pandas forward fill entire rows according to missing integers in specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to figure out a clean way to forward fill entire rows based on missing integers in a specific column. For example I have the dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'frame':[0,3,5], 'value': [1,2,3]})`

```
   frame  value
0      0      1
1      3      2
2      5      3
```

And I'd like to create new rows where the `frame` column has integer gaps, and the values are forward filled for all other columns. For example the output in this case would look like:

```
   frame  value
0      0      1
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      3      2
4      4      2
5      5      3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `frame` as index and `reindex` with `ffill`:

```
frame_range = np.arange(df['frame'].min(), df['frame'].max()+1)
df.set_index('frame').reindex(frame_range).ffill().reset_index()
```

Or you can also use `merge` then `ffill`

```
# frame_range as above
df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'frame':frame_range}),
         on='frame', how='outer').ffill()
```

Output:

```
   frame  value
0      0    1.0
1      1    1.0
2      2    1.0
3      3    2.0
4      4    2.0
5      5    3.0
```

---

**Update**: `merge_asof` is actually a better choice:

```
pd.merge_asof(pd.DataFrame({'frame':frame_range}),
              df,
              on='frame')
```

Output:

```
   frame  value
0      0      1
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      3      2
4      4      2
5      5      3
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost perfect, though it seems it changes the dtypes from ints to floats on the value column?

Comment: @Austin that's because when you reindex/merge, the missing frames have `NaN` values, which downcasts  the column to float. But you can always convert back.

Comment: Ah okay, will it be an issue if I have other columns that are categorical or object types?

Comment: Actually, you can better use `merge_asof`. Updated